# How to get the cross forest membership of the user in C#?

Tags: c#, active-directory, cross-domain, membership

I have two trust forest A and B, user C belong to forest A and group D belong to forest B. Then I assign user C to group D.

My question is, I want to get all the membership of user C. Do anyone know how to do that in C#?

I have tried some .net API, but I just get the membership of the current domain for the user. I know the "member" property store the membership, but do I need to search all the groups in trust forest and check the "member" property to achieve this?

The test program below is what I tried to get the trust forest membership. Domain "a.com" is from forest A and domain "b.com" is from forest B.

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "a.com"))
{
    using (PrincipalContext ctx2 = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "b.com"))
    {
        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "C");
        var groups1 = user.GetGroups(ctx); // only get the memebership of a.com
        var groups2 = user.GetGroups(ctx2); // cannot get the membership of b.com
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a repro case of the code you've tried so far?

Comment: @M.Babcock Thanks for your reply, I have added my test code I have tried. Beside that, I still tried to check the "memberof" property of the user, but it still didn't work.